# Solve the set of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Taking the sets

$-4x_1 +x_2 = 3$

$8x_1 -2x_2 =-6$

I add them together and get

$4x_1 - x_2=-3$

thus $x_1 = -3/4 - 1/4x_2$
and $ x_2 = +3 + 4x_1$

I need to solve it as $ x_1 = ____ + ____ $
and $ x_2 = ____ + ____ $

Comment: You can't solve explicitly if you don't use some technique to remove one of the variables.  Systems of equations can have 1, 0, or an infinite amount of solutions.  You can use many techniques, including graphing, substitution, and elimination....

Comment: Note what happens if you multiply the top by 2 and then add....

Comment: Already answered below @Eleven-Eleven

Answer (score 0):

You get the second equation by multiplying the first equation by a factor of $-2$

This means that these two are simultaneous equations. If one of them is satisfied, then the other is automatically satisfied. There would be infinite solutions.